# Recursive type definition

Tags: typescript

**Scenario**

Given the following object

```
const obj = {
  entry: 'legend',
  fauna: {
    unicorns: 10,
    zombies: 3
  },
  other: {
    hat: 2
  }
}
```

I'm trying to declare a type that allows a subset of properties from the above type but each value must be a function from that value's type to the same type

For example the following:

```
const addOne = (x:number) => x + 1

const upperCase = (x:string) => x.toUpperCase()

const mapping = {
  entry: upperCase,
  fauna: {
    unicorns: addOne
  },
  other: obj => ({
      hat: addOne(obj.hat)
  })
}
```

**Attempt**

I tried the following definition but it appears to fail on the nested properties

```
type MapPropFuncsOf<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: (x:T[P]) => T[P] | MapPropFuncsOf<T[P]>
}

const mapping: MapPropFuncsOf<typeof obj> = {
  entry: upperCase,
  fauna: {
    unicorns: addOne
  },
  other: obj => ({
      hat: addOne(obj.hat)
  })
}
```

> Type '{ unicorns: (x: number) => number; }' is not assignable to type
>   '(x: { unicorns: number; zombies: number; }) => { unicorns: number;
>   zombies: number; } | MapPropFuncsOf<{ unicorns: number; zombies:
>   number; }>'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
>   'unicorns' does not exist in type '(x: { unicorns: number; zombies:
>   number; }) => { unicorns: number; zombies: number; } |
>   MapPropFuncsOf<{ unicorns: number; zombies: number; }>'

Comment: (correct me if I'm wrong) you want a function to return such an object, and that function to be part of the main object. Why? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a simple case of missing `()`. `(x:T[P]) => T[P] | MapPropFuncsOf<T[P]>` means a function that returns `T[P] | MapPropFuncsOf<T[P]>`. You probably want a function (with this signature `(x:T[P]) => T[P]`) or `MapPropFuncsOf<T[P]>`.

This will work

```
type MapPropFuncsOf<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: ((x:T[P]) => T[P]) | MapPropFuncsOf<T[P]>
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MapPropFuncsOf%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20((x%3AT%5BP%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BP%5D)%20%7C%20MapPropFuncsOf%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20addOne%20%3D%20(x%3Anumber)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%201%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20upperCase%20%3D%20(x%3Astring)%20%3D%3E%20x.toUpperCase()%0D%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20entry%3A%20'legend'%2C%0D%0A%20%20fauna%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20unicorns%3A%2010%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20zombies%3A%203%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20other%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hat%3A%202%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20mapping%3A%20MapPropFuncsOf%3Ctypeof%20obj%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20entry%3A%20upperCase%2C%0D%0A%20%20fauna%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20unicorns%3A%20addOne%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20other%3A%20obj%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hat%3A%20addOne(obj.hat)%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Thanks for your help .. I'm still struggling to convert my implementation to typescript though .. `MapPropFuncsOf` is a discriminated union but I'm not sure how to tell typescript that its a function in one case but a `MapPropFuncsOf` in another? [Playground link](https://pastebin.com/KNweh7tB)